# How would I normalize the slope of a line?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Assuming I have different lines with different slopes, I would like to compare the slope of each line as relative to one another. 
The program I am currently writing needs to compare the slopes of the lines on a 0 to 1 basis (1 being very steep, or equivalent of a slope of infinity and 0 being equivalent to a slope of 0) 
However, right now I have the values of the slope in absolute form, going from 0 to infinity. May I know how to accurately map these slopes to a scale of 0 to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slope measure form 0 to 1 is basically an angle (lets call it $\alpha$), the other one is the slope, lets call it $m$. The relation is

$$ m = \tan\left( \alpha  \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$$ if you are calculating with *radians* or

$$ m = \tan\left( \alpha \cdot 90° \right)$$ if you are calculating in *degrees*.

Comment: So if I have the slope 'm', then I can get the 0-1 value as 
alpha = arctan(m)/(pi/2)?

Comment: @user3705895 Yes.

Comment: @user3705895 exactly.

Comment: Why is there the multiplication of the angle by pi/2? @flawr

Comment: Is it because arctan(m) < pi/2 so that by dividing it by pi/2 we get the 0-1 scale?

Comment: Yes, the values between 0 and 1 correspond to angles between $0$ and $\pi/2$.